# database design to speed up application

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, nosql, search-engine

I have 2 tables,

first table stores URLs

`|link_id | link_url |` <== schema url_table ::: Contains 2 million+ rows

and second table stores user_bookmarks

`|user_id| link_id | is_bookmarked |` <== schema for user_table ::: over 3.5 million+ rows

is_bookmarked stores 1 or 0, according to the link being bookmarked by the user or not.

Here is the problem,

When a new link is added, these are the steps followed 
1) Check if url already exists in url_table , which means going through millions of rows
2)if does not exist add a new row in url_table and user_table

The Database(Mysql) is simply taking too much time, due to the enormous row-set,
Also, its a very simple php+Mysql app, with no search-assisted indexing programs whatsoever.

any suggestions to speed this up?

Comment: Any indexes you have created on your table? i not you could try creating indexes for starters

Comment: And after checking indexes, do an EXPLAIN for the query that you're using

Comment: How long does `SELECT count(*) as total FROM firstTable WHERE \`link_url\`='www.someUrl.com/something/more/to/this'` take exactly?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus 4 seconds

Comment: i do have an index for `link_url` search times are large for querying links from `url_table` `select *.. where link_url='link'`

Comment: What kind of memory limit is imposed by your hosting provider? I know basic plans are usually 512 MB so any scripts or DB indexing which your server has to run is eating into that limited resource.

Comment: about 1GB Ram on the server, but yeah, there are other processes sharing that. I'd like a solution to  optimize the queries on the resources already available.

Comment: Does your provider give you some sort of cPanel with a task manager of some sort? Maybe the CPU is simply being spiked to 100% and so your query just has to wait. Also, rather than doing a `SELECT count(*)`, maybe you can make the `link_url` a primary key and simply send insert commands regardless. Using PHP you can check if the insert succeeded or not

Comment: This should be solvable through straight-forward application of indexing. Could you post your exact queries (and the accompanying execution plans)?

Answer (score 1):

Why not remove the column `user_bookmarks.is_bookmarked` and use the sole existence of an entry with user_id and link_id as indicator that the link was bookmarked?

A new link has no entries in the user_bookmarks table, because nobody bookmarked it yet. When a user bookmarks a link, you add an entry. When the user removes the bookmark, you remove the row.

To check if a user bookmarked a link or not, simply `SELECT count() FROM user_bookmarks WHERE user_id=? AND link_id=?`. When you receive 1 row, it is bookmarked. When you receive 0 rows, it isn't.

Speeding up the insert-query when adding a new entry in the URL table could be accelerated with an appropriate index.

Comment: did'nt mention it in the question, but the `user_bookmarks` has more columns such as `is_visited` etc.. and is'nt `count()` an expensive operation?

Comment: @wolfgang You could evaluate some NoSQL solutions, but your problem is so generic that it would work fine with any database technology. Count is only expensive when you have no proper indexes.

Answer (score 0):

If you told us what your curent schema was (i.e. the create table statements including indexes) rather than just what your column names were then we might be able to make practical suggestions as to how to improve that.

There's certainly scope for improving the method of adding rows:

Assuming that the link_url can be larger than the 767 byte limit for an Innodb table (you didn't say what engine you are using), then change the id column to contain a md5 hash of the link_url with a unique index. Then when you want to add a record, go ahead and try to insert it using INSERT IGNORE ....

Comment: the `link_id` is auto-incremented, how would using an md5 hash as the unique index on `link_id` perform better?

Comment: It omits 2 round trips to the database and the index is directly derived from the url hence queries using the URL can use an index.